# Lazy load Aurelia plugin

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

I have a large plugin (abalmus/aurelia-ace-editor) that I'm trying to load into Aurelia and it's hurting my page load time. Does anyone know how to load an Aurelia plugin other than on app start?

Main.ts:

```
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
    .plugin('aurelia-validatejs')
    .plugin('aurelia-animator-css')
    .plugin('abalmus/aurelia-ace-editor')
    .plugin('aurelia-cookie')
    .feature('lib/form-validation-renderer');

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In whatever module you want to load the the plugin, reference both the `Aurelia` class and the `FrameworkConfiguration` class from the `aurelia-framework` module:

```
import { Aurelia, FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';
```

Get a reference to the Aurelia object in the ctor:

```
  constructor(private aurelia: Aurelia) { }
```

Then, in an appropriate place (such as the `activate` function), create a new `FrameworkConfiguration` object and load the plugin:

```
activate() {
  return new FrameworkConfiguration(this.aurelia).plugin('abalmus/aurelia-ace-editor').apply();
}
```

For more reading
https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/145